# Using serverAuthCode to retrive refreshToken and accessToken - code sample

Tags: google-api, google-api-java-client, google-api-client, google-signin

From google API docs [url](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/offline-access) at the last paragraph "*Securely pass the serverAuthCode string to your server, which will exchange the code for an access token and a refresh token*". I am not sure what to do with `serverAuthCode`. Where is code sample that uses `serverAuthCode` to get `accessToken` and `refreshToken`?

Comment: I am facing same problem. Did you get solution for this?

Comment: did you get the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

the solution given by com.iavian is perfect,

in my case i was getting serverAuthCode from https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin,

in the backend then you can do below code

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;

    public static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
    public static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();
GoogleTokenResponse response = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, Your_OAUTH_CLIENTID, Your_OAUTH_CLIENTSECRET, Serverauthcode_from_react_native, "").execute();
```

Note: The serverAuthCode can be used only once , from the response that you get you should store the refreshToken, and from next time use refreshToken to get you AccessToken

Answer (score -1):

Below is how one has to do

```
GoogleTokenResponse response = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(httpTransport, jsonFactory, Main.GMAIL_OAUTH_CLIENTID, Main.GMAIL_OAUTH_CLIENTSECRET, X.getServerauthcode(), "").execute();
X.setServeraccesstoken(response.getAccessToken());
X.setServerrefreshtoken(response.getRefreshToken());
```